# 401 ERROR when creating new recipe and adding it to the table 'recipes'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, passport.js

When trying to CREATE a new recipe and add it to the database, I get a 401 Unauthorized error message.

It probably has something to do with the following...:

Profile.js (where a REGISTERED user sees all of THEIR recipes, can CREATE, UPDATE & DELETE recipes) is a protected route, only REGISTERED users can see content on this page.
When someone does the signup or login, they are redirected to Profile.js.

The Problem: Anyone who logs in or signs up, can see all recipes - although I have created a Foreign key, linking recipe_user (user_id) from recipes to id from users.

I believe because this doesn't work properly - the create also doesn't work.

I tried putting console.log at various places to determine where it goes wrong, I've tried different values - nothing worked...

Find all relevant code here:
https://gist.github.com/MisterSemaan/07d7cf52b0069d2ea89b29f608c2b976

Here are the most relevant sections from my code:

__In Profile.js
GET -->

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt')
    console.log(jwt)
    if (jwt) {
      axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost:4000/api/recipes',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwt
        }
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        this.setState({data: response.data.recipes})
      })
    }
  }
```

CREATE -->

```
handleClick(event){
   const jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt')
   console.log(jwt)
   axios({
     method: 'post',
     data: {
      name: this.state.recipe_name,
      author: this.state.recipe_author,
      meal: this.state.recipe_meal,
      description: this.state.recipe_description,
      ingredients: this.state.recipe_ingredients,
      preparation: this.state.recipe_preparation
     },
     url: 'http://localhost:4000/api/recipe',
     headers: {
       'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwt
     }
   }).then((response) => {
     console.log(response)
     this.setState({ recipe: response.data.recipes });
   }).catch((error, res) => {
    if(error.response.status === 401) {
       console.log("Error:", error);
       alert("Failed")
     }
   })
 }
```

Render -->

```
render(){
    return (
    <div>
      <div className="newRecipe">
        <TextField helperText="Enter the name of your recipe" label="name" onChange = {(event) => this.setState({name: data.recipe_name})}/>
        <br/>
        <TextField helperText="Enter your name" label="Author" onChange = {(event) => this.setState({author: data.recipe_author})}/>
        <br/>
        <TextField helperText="Enter the mealtype" label="meal" onChange = {(event) => this.setState({meal: data.recipe_meal})}/>
        <br/>
        <TextField helperText="Enter a short description of your recipe" label="description" onChange = {(event) => this.setState({description: data.recipe_description})}/>
        <br/>
        <TextField helperText="Enter the ingredients" label="ingredients" onChange = {(event) => this.setState({ingredients: data.recipe_ingredients})}/>
        <br/>
        <TextField helperText="Enter the preparation method" label="preparation" onChange = {(event) => this.setState({preparation: data.recipe_preparation})}/>
        <br/>
      </div>
      <Button color="secondary" onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}>Submit Recipe</Button>
      <div className="RecipeCard">
        {
          this.state.data && this.state.data.map((data, key) => {
            return <RecipeCard name={data.recipe_name} author={data.recipe_author} meal={data.recipe_meal} description={data.recipe_description} ingredients={data.recipe_ingredients} preparation={data.recipe_preparation}/>
          })
        }
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
```

__In index.js

// Profile ROUTE - PROTECTED
    api.get('/recipes', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res) => {
            db.query('SELECT * FROM recipes', (err, rows) => {
                res.json({recipes: rows});
            })
    });

```
// Profile ROUTE - PROTECTED
api.get('/recipes', (req, res) => {
        const id = req.query.user_id;
        console.log(req.query)
        db.query('SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE user_id = ?', [user_id] , (err, rows) => {
            res.json({recipes: rows});
        })
});

// Profile CREATE ROUTE - PROTECTED
api.post('/recipe', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res) => {
        const recipe = {
            name: req.body.recipe_name,
            author: req.body.recipe_author,
            meal: req.body.recipe_meal,
            description: req.body.recipe_description,
            ingredients: req.body.recipe_ingredients,
            preparation: req.body.recipe_preparation
        }
        db.query('INSERT INTO recipes SET ?', recipe, (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500)
                return;
            }
            db.query('SELECT * FROM recipes', (err, rows) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500)
                    return;
                }
                res.json({recipes: rows});
            })
        })
});
```

__In index.js jwt

```
var jwtOptions = {}
jwtOptions.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
jwtOptions.secretOrKey = config.secret;
passport.use(new Strategy(jwtOptions, function(jwt_payload, next) {
    console.log('payload received', jwt_payload);
    db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [jwt_payload.email], (err, rows) => {
        let user = null
        if(rows && rows[0]){
            user = rows[0]
        }
        if (user) {
            next(null, user);
        } else {
            next(null, false);
        }
    })
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
```

__In init.sql

recipes table-->

```
CREATE TABLE `recipes` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `recipe_image` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recipe_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `recipe_meal` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `recipe_author` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `recipe_description` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `recipe_ingredients` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `recipe_preparation` varchar(400) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `recipe_complete` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `recipe_user` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `recipe_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

users table-->

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Please add your code *to the question*, not linked-to off-site.  We need a [mcve], not your entire project.

Comment: I didn't add my entire project - I added all the relevant code to gist.github

Comment: Again, your code needs to be **in the question**, not linked off site.  And we don't need hundreds of lines of code; please distill your question down to a [mcve].

Comment: Now it is  in here and not off site : )

Comment: you know, instead of just giving me minus points, you can try to help me : )

Comment: I could, but your question has a lot of code in it.  It would take a lot of time to go through it. I feel it's not worth the investment in time. It's why we ask for a *minimal* example.

Comment: ok so if I'll post something again - and be way more concise with my code? It will be reviewed and I might be helped?

Comment: Assuming sufficient code exists in the question for volunteers to fully understand the problem, less code means less time involvement, which increases the likelihood of receiving an answer. You can edit this question and clean it up. Doing so will move it into the active questions queue and probably to stack overflows homepage, same as asking a new question would.

Comment: ok thank you for explaining this to me.
I have created a new question (I actually solved this problem :P but am now stuck on another one :/ )

Comment: OK, you can answer your own question and get some free rep. Or, if that doesn't interest, just delete this question. There's no penalty unless you do that repeatedly.

Comment: oh cool I can? niceeee : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I could explain why it works, but I'm not that knowledgeable in react.js.
So here's just what I changed:

__In Profile.js, all the TextFields

FROM::
data.recipe_name

TO::
event.target.value

__In Profile.js, handleClick the data

FROM::
name: this.state.recipe_name,

TO::
name: this.state.name,

__In Profile.js, this.state

FROM::
data: []

TO::
name: '',
author: '',
meal: '',
description: '',
ingredients: '',
preparation: ''

__In Profile.js, this.setState (I'm still not 100% if this is correct)

FROM::
this.setState({ recipe: response.data.recipes });

TO::
this.setState({ recipe: response.data.recipe });

I think that's it? If I find any other fixes, I will keep this updated : )
Cheers